# Problem with orientation of social media icons to position them horizontally

Tags: html, css

I almost have my social media icons the way I want them. The problem that I'm having is that my icons show vertical when I want them horizontal. As soon as I added floating text to the code, the icons switched from horizontal to vertical. I can't figure out how to get them horizontal again without taking out the floating text that I want to keep. I plan to use this code in the footer of my wordpress site with the custom html option in the widget options.

As soon as I added floating text to the images, the icons switched from horizontal to vertical. I cant figure out how to keep the images horizontal and I don't want to get rid of the floating text.

How can I line up the images horizontally?

```html
<center>

  <div title="twitter">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/eb71c669616b73376b4046d59aa72acd-full.jpg" border="0" / alt="twitter_" src="https://ibb.co/hXDMqVP" width="85" height="85">
  </div>
  </a>

  <div title="patreon">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/7c336d8d73312b913f3cb0d3d29f924f-full.jpg" border="0" / border="0" alt="patreon" src="https://ibb.co/hXDMqVP" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  </a>

  <div title="ko-fi">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/afe4f098fcf4ce4781aa0a0bea7c5f5d-full.jpg" border="0" / alt="ko-fi" src="https://ibb.co/hXDMqVP" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  </a>

</center>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>` elements are "[block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)":

> By default, a block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block." ... Browsers typically display the block-level element with a newline both before and after the element. You can visualize them as a stack of boxes ... A block-level element **always starts on a new line** and takes up the full width available (stretches out to the left and right as far as it can).

One basic method to display the items horizontally is to add the `title` attributes directly to the `<a>` elements, which are "[inline elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements)":

> Inline elements are those which only occupy the space bounded by the tags defining the element, instead of breaking the flow of the content ... An inline element **does not start on a new line** and only takes up as much width as necessary.

Here's a demonstration:

```css
#container {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <a href="#" target="_blank" title="twitter">
    <img src="" border="0" width="50" height="50">
  </a>

  <a href="#" target="_blank" title="patreon">
    <img src="" border="0" width="50" height="50">
  </a>

  <a href="#" target="_blank" title="ko-fi">
    <img src="" border="0" width="50" height="50">
  </a>

</div>
```

For more information, see [CSS Layout - Normal Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow).

The above is a very simple layout. Other more sophisticated methods might be useful, for example if you want to distribute the items across the screen with space between them.

See [CSS Layout Guides](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout#Guides).

---

Also note that the HTML in your code seems to be malformed. The `<div>` and `<a>` elements are not nested correctly. The `<img>` elements have duplicate attributes and misplaced slashes. And, as others have mentioned, the [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) element is obsolete.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick! I got the images properly centered the way I wanted them. Also, thank you for the extra information on CSS and to look into nesting the code correctly.

Answer (score 2):

The `center` tag is obselete. Wrap it with a `div` and set it to flex

```css
.icon-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="icon-container">
  <div title="twitter">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/eb71c669616b73376b4046d59aa72acd-full.jpg" border="0" / alt="twitter_" src="https://ibb.co/hXDMqVP" width="85" height="85">
  </div>
  </a>


  <div title="patreon">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/7c336d8d73312b913f3cb0d3d29f924f-full.jpg" border="0" / border="0" alt="patreon" src="https://ibb.co/hXDMqVP" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  </a>


  <div title="ko-fi">
    <a href="" target="_blank"><img src="https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/6/19/afe4f098fcf4ce4781aa0a0bea7c5f5d-full.jpg" border="0" / alt="ko-fi" src="https://ibb.co/hXDMqVP" width="100" height="100">
  </div>
  </a>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `float: left;` property for every div contains an image.